# Scalabel slider

Tags: c#, xaml

I have custom slider style. Main problem that it doesnot scale when i change height in  `<Slider Height="20" Width="280" Style="{StaticResource MyCustomStyleForSlider}"></Slider>`. I tried to change `RepeatButton` `Height`, it does nothing, why?

```
<Style x:Key="CustomThumbForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF462857" StrokeThickness="0" Height="15" Width="5"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MyCustomStyleForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Top" Height="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Bottom" Height="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="4.0" Grid.Row="1" >
                                <Canvas Margin="-6,-1">
                                    <Rectangle Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Height="4.0" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1.0"/>
                                </Canvas>
                            </Border>
                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Background="#FF8D7D97" BorderThickness="1 1 0 1"/>
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Background="#FFC6BCCC" BorderThickness="0 1 1 1"/>
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="Black" Style="{StaticResource CustomThumbForSlider}"/>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Grid>
    <Slider Height="20" Width="280" Style="{StaticResource MyCustomStyleForSlider}"></Slider>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will someone help. Solution is very simple. It need only to past `Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}"` in `<Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" >`. Ando also make this operation with thumb style.

```
        <Style x:Key="CustomThumbForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF462857" StrokeThickness="0" Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}" Width="4"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyCustomStyleForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Top" Height="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Bottom" Height="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="4.0" Grid.Row="1" >
                                <Canvas Margin="-6,-1">
                                    <Rectangle Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Height="4.0" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1.0"/>
                                </Canvas>
                            </Border>
                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}">
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Background="#FF8D7D97" BorderThickness="1 1 0 1"/>
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Background="#FFC6BCCC" BorderThickness="0 1 1 1"/>
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="Black" Style="{StaticResource CustomThumbForSlider}"/>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```